# translate string by value in locale

Tags: android

Does android API support translating string resources by value?

I know that I can create multiple XML files for different locale. My problem is that I am getting the values from the server in a "default locale" so, I can't use `getString(int)`.

I want something like `getTranslation("myValueInDefaultLocale", "target locale")`

Comment: you want to android to translate string for you? , if that is what you want then no it doesnt

Comment: @ColdFire No, I already defined the translated values in the strings.xml. I just want to access the the translated value (for a locale) by the default locale

Comment: if you are getting values from server you have all the string you can easily get the strings you know

Comment: What we did in our Server architecture, is to allow the client calling the API specifying the language. For instance: GET "/pages/{language}/home". I wouldn't advise to let the application switch the locale, it is not a common practice.

Comment: @ColdFire the server returns the values in the default locale

Answer (score 1):

There is no efficient way to do what you are asking, but to modify the server. If you can't change server, then you can do this:

1. Save current locale
2. Switch to default locale programmatically
3. Iterate through all string resources looking for specific string
4. Save ID of the string
5. Switch back to saved locale
6. Get translated value of string by ID in desired locale

But this will work **really slow**. Don't say I didn't warn you.

Here is the code sample:

```
String translateFrom = "server reply";

Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;
conf.locale = defaultLocale; // set to default locale here
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);

// iterate through all string resources in default locale
int idTranslateTo = 0;
Field fields[] = R.string.class.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(field.getName(), "string", this.getPackageName()));
    if (translateFrom.equals(res.getString(id)) {
        idTranslateTo = id;
        break;
    }
}

// restore original locale
conf.locale = savedLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);

// retrieve translated string from saved locale
if (idTranslateTo != 0) {
    String translateTo = res.getString(idTranslateTo);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I changed my API on the server to accept locale parameter and get the translated value instead .